# Use Link in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I start to create an application using next js. Adding a link like:

```js
<Link href={"/home"}><a>Home</a></Link>
```

... causes an error:

[image]

Why appears it?

Comment: try ```npm run build``` then ```npm run start```

Comment: please post your `_document.tsx` file here. Because thats where the error is located